# Positioned Off-Screen vs Hidden

Tags: ios, swift, animation, memory, interface-builder

I'm building an app in Xcode, using interface builder. One VC has some objects I have positioned off-screen (-600 leading to leading margin, for example). On button press, they are animated into the view.

My question is, what is the effect of having views off screen? Does it take up memory? Should I hide these views after they've animated back off to the side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any view that has been alloc'ed and init'ed will take up memory, off screen or not.  This is more obvious in Obj-c as its when you call `[UIView alloc] init]` buts its still the same in swift `UIView(frame: )`.

The view won't draw its layers until it's been added as a subview.  The view will still draw itself if it's off the parents visible rect by default.  You can set the parents view to `clipsToBounds = YES` (swift `clipsToBounds = true`)  and it won't draw any of its child views off screen saving some memory as the child views won't draw their layers.  Not sure it's worth the effort to do that though as you only have them off screen temporarily and then animate on.

If you can you should instantiate the views right before you animate them on screen,  you should 'removeFromSuperview' and set to nil, or remove them from your array, however you are storing them once the animation is done.